# Calculation of $p$-Sylow's subgroups of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

We consider the group $S_3$ with its $6$ elements: $i$, $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$, $\tau_3$. My definition of a $p$-Sylow's subgroup of a finite group $G$ is: let $H<G$, $|H|=p^r$ with $|H|$ be the maximum power of $p$ that divides $|G|$, then $H$ is called a $p$-Sylow's subgroup of $G$. Now let's proceed with the exercise: the order of any $2$-Sylow's subgroup is $2$, while the order of any $3$-Sylow's subgroup is $3$ because $|S_3|=6=3*2$. I honestly don't understad why with simply factorising $|S_3|$ we got the order of the $2$-Sylow's subgroups and the order of the $3$-Sylow's subgroups in $S_3$. Given that, the exercise becomes easy as: $\tau_1^2=i=\tau_2^2=\tau_3^2$ and $\sigma_1^2=\sigma_2$ while $\sigma_2^2=\sigma_1$. So, $[i,\tau_1]$;$[i,\tau_2]$;$[i,\tau_3]$ are all the $2$-Sylow's subgroups of $S_3$ because they are all the $2$ order subgroups in general, while $[i,\sigma_1,\sigma_2]$ is the only $3$-Sylow's subgroup of $S_3$ because it is the only $3$ order subgroup in $S_3$.

Comment: Usual notation is $S_3$, not $S^3$.

Comment: You are right and I also mixed notations. Can I edit the question itself in a way ?

Comment: Yes. Click on the "edit" link at the bottom and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $6=2^1\cdot 3^1$, the highest power for $2$ in the factorization is $1$, hence, the Sylow 2-subgroup has the order $2^1$, and similarly the Sylow 3-subgroup has the order $3^1$.

By Sylow 3rd theorem, if the number of Sylow p-subgroup is $k$, then $k\equiv1\pmod p$, and $k|n$, where $n$ is the order of the group $G$. In your case, $G=S_3$.

Suppose there are totally $k_2$ Sylow 2-subgroup, then, $k_2\equiv1\pmod 2$, and $k_2|6$. Therefore, $k_2=1$ or $k_2=3$. Since you have found $3$ Sylow 2-subgroup, then $k_2\neq 1$, hence $k_2=3$. So the three Sylow 2-subgroups are the only subgroups of order $2$.

Similarly, suppose there are totally $k_3$ Sylow 3-subgroup, then, $k_3\equiv1\pmod 3$, and $k_3|6$. Therefore, $k_3=1$ is the only possible case, which means there is only one Sylow 3-subgroup, and actually it is $A_3$.

=================

If this exercise is before Sylow's 3rd theorem, then you can verify it by hand. For example, if you are looking at Sylow's 2-subgroup, denoted by $H$, then $H$ must contain two elements, one of them must be $e$, so let $H=\{e, x\}$, then $x^2=e$, which means the $x$ can only take $\tau_i, i=1,2,3$, (hence totally $3$ Sylow 2-subgroups), because those $\sigma_i$ has order $3$, hence $x$ cannot be those $\sigma_i$.

Similarly, Sylow 3-subgroups cannot contain any of those $\tau_i$, because the order of element must divide the order of the subgroup. But $|\tau_i|=2\nmid 3$, so there is only one Sylow 3-subgroup and it includes all those $\sigma_i$ elements.

Comment: The exercise was actually presented before Sylow's third theorem, but this makes sense.

Comment: I add more words to show how to solve it without using Sylow's 3rd theorem. @matteoC1729